# huawei y6 pro in bootloop:(

Tags: boot-loop, huawei

Today, after installing custom firmware into my Huawei Y6PRO it shows only boot (bootloop), and I went to fastboot mode, and by mistake turn on lock on bootloader :( so now I can't go into recovery mode, nothing happens when I click pawer + volume up / volume down or both:( any advise how to fix it?:(

Comment: Can you still enter fastboot mode? (Hold volume down and plug in a USB cable connected to your computer)

Comment: @ThunderStorm no:(

Comment: Is there any other way to enter fastboot mode?

Comment: None that I am aware of. You might want to use google.

Comment: Simply flash a stock firmware. You'll need an SD card for that

Comment: @esQmo_ ok, but how do that, if I can't go into recovery or fastboot?

Comment: @ThunderStorm ok, but how?

Comment: Huawei devices doesn't need recovery or fastboot to be flashed. There is a flash mode that can be used for that.

Comment: @esQmo_ ok, how can I go into that? what I need? could u help me with that? I have SD card:)

Comment: Please check my answer and follow the steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just read the specs and it appears that this phone model is powered by a Mediatek chip (MT6735P), so the SD card method won't work. We'll need a computer for that.

Assuming you have a Windows or Linux computer:

1. Download the firmware from this [site](http://consumer.huawei.com/np/support/products/downloads/detail/y6-pro-np.htm?id=94465)
2. Download SP Flashtool [here](http://spflashtool.com/)
3. Only required by Windows: Download MTK CDC, VCOM drivers [here](https://androidmtk.com/download-mtk-usb-all-drivers) (Needed for the device to be detected by the computer as android preloader)

To start, unzip the firmware, SP Flashtool and (on Windows) install the drivers.

Now open Flashtool then click on Scatter-download. Browse to the firmware folder that you unzipped. Select a text file (`MTxxxx_Android_scatter`). Some files should load into SP Flashtool.

**Important:** Unselect the Preloader (Flashing the Preloader may permanently kill your phone).

Now click on Download (green arrow) then power off the phone (leave battery inside), connect the USB cable (Windows should install drivers).

Once USB cable is connected, the flashing process should start automatically. Wait till the end.

A big green check mark should pop. You're done.

Edit:
Another download link: http://consumer.huawei.com/np/support/products/downloads/detail/y6-pro-np.htm?id=87066

Edit 2:
Contrary to what I said before, the SD card method can be used on this model too. Follow this [link](http://firmwarerom.com/huawei-y6-pro-tit-al00) get the files and a step by step guide. This site seems to have many ads, be careful and download only flashing files.

Update 3 SD Card method:

1. Unzip the firmware file
2. You'll find a folder labeled `dload` which contains `UPDATE.APP`
3. Plug the SD Card into the computer (use an adapter)
4. Copy that folder into the root of the SD card put back in the phone
5. Now hold <kbd>volume up</kbd> + <kbd>volume down</kbd> and briefly touch the <kbd>power</kbd> button.
6. The flashing process should start automatically

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138092/discussion-on-answer-by-esqmo-huawei-y6-pro-in-bootloop).